MS Graph (or SP) not recognizing index on a list
I have a basic list (empty atm - not sure if that's relevant). There are a couple of Lookups, Text, currency and number columns.
For the purpose of this question the Lookup column in question is named X and the number column is named Y.
There are following indices defined:

single X
compound X,Y
some other single and compound

When running following query in MS graph:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<<siteId>>/lists/<<listId>/items?$filter=fields/XLookupId eq '341' and fields/Y eq 202404&$expand=fields

I get the error: Y column is not indexed.
When I delete the single X index the error is basically the same just refers to the column first in the filter.
Only when I create a single Y index does the query run with no issues.
I'm familiar with SQL indexing; how is the SP indexing different from that? And what use is there for compounds, when the are not being used? Is it enough to use single column indices even for queries, where I'm looking at 3-4 columns in the filter?
thx
P.S.: I'm aware of the "Prefer": "HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly" header and don't want to use it (at least not in this instance)
